# Why does Google App Engine flex build step fail while standard works for the same code?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Our nodejs application works fine in GAE Standard. But we need to use websockets so we are going with Flex. However we are running into all sorts of build-time issues with Flex.

So we want to deploy a GAE Flex with a `gcp-build` step, but are getting all sorts of errors such as:

`Step #1: error building image: error building stage: symlink /app/packages/node_modules/autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer /app/packages/client/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer: file exists`

and also, after patching that, comes this error:

`error building image: read tcp 192.168.10.2:54502->74.125.20.128:443: read: connection reset by peer`

We are on a mono-repo app with lerna and our `gcp-build` script just does: `yarn build` which subsequently does: `"build": "lerna run build --scope=client --scope=server --scope=common --stream"`

---

We have a hunch that `gcp-build` is only for the standard env and not flex. If that is truly so, how would you recommend us to run a build step in GAE Flex? And if not, what is with all these 'building image' errors? All is fine in GAE Standard with the same code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got our flex server running. So here are the answers to my initial questions:

---

Firstly, the error `Step #1: error building image: error building stage: symlink /app/packages/node_modules/autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer /app/packages/client/node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer: file exists` was solved by running `yarn build && rm -rf ./packages/client/node_modules` in our gcp-build step.

---

Cannot repro the second error about `error building image: read tcp 192.168.10.2:54502->74.125.20.128:443: read: connection reset by peer` and later found that it was probably due to my internet connection dropping out during the deployment as advised by a gcloud support agent quoted below:

> It means that the build failed because the library was absent, this IP did not respond at this time.

---

Lastly, regarding the third question about whether gcp-build is only for the standard env and not flex. It's not true. It works in both standard and flex as quoted by the same agent:

> Regarding the question about  that ‘gcp-build’ is only for the standard env and not flex, that is not correct, you can use gcp-build, in the App Engine Standard and Flex [1].