# Next-JS App on Google App Engine - Could not find a valid build

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I receive the following error message after deploying my Next.js app on Google Cloud's AppEngine. Before deploying the app I run `npm run-scrip build` locally. Starting the app locally does work fine as well.

While deploying `glcoud app deploy` I do not receive any error. After opening the app `gcloud app browse` I receive server response [500].

In the log I find following error:

```
   Error: Could not find a valid build in the '/workspace/.next' directory! Try building your app with 'next build' before starting the server.
    at Server.readBuildId (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:137)
    at Server (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/next-server/server/next-server.js:3)
    at createServer (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js:2)
    at start (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:1)
    at nextStart (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-start.js:19)
    at (/workspace/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:26)
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "next-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
    "preinstall": "node lock_node_version.js"
  }
```

app.yaml file:

```
env: standard
runtime: nodejs14
service: default
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    script: auto
```

**EDIT/ADDED**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.6",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^4.0.0",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "apollo-server-micro": "^2.19.0",
    "check-node-version": "^4.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "firebase": "^8.2.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lowdb": "^1.0.0",
    "next": "10.0.3",
    "next-i18next": "^7.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.1.1"
  }
,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lowdb": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.10",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.9.0",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2"
  },
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66739187/7031308

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo Thanks for your response I added the `gcp-build`:`tsc-p` command to package.json and redeployed the app as suggested in the github repository but got the same error. Do I need to add more arguments because there are more dependecies, except typescript (I updated my initial post)? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need typescript as it's just part of the example. What you need to do is change `build` from scripts to `gcp-build`. For example: `"gcp-build": "next build"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the same identical behavior of `build` script to build your app before deployment in App Engine by using `gcp-build`. It is well documented on GCP [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/running-custom-build-step) and here's an example for you:

```
 "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "gcp-build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8080",
    "preinstall": "node lock_node_version.js"
  }
```

To address the confusion in the comments, you may have noticed that in the docs, the command `tsc -p .` specified as a custom build step. What it does is it compiles Typescript code because the example itself is a Typescript app. You don't need to run it unless you're using Typescript. It's always up to you and you're free to specify any commands when using `gcp-build`.